# Как записать значение в регистр Modbus C#

Tags: c#, modbus

Как записать значение в определенный регистр Modbus C#?
С простой отправкой данных на Com port проблем не возникало, а вот по поводу определенного регистра не могу найти информации.

Comment: Думаю для примера, это должно помочь [ссылка](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FC06.htm)

Comment: Только не понятно какой у меня Slave Address и остальные числа...